# using JaxB to unmarshall object which contains List<String> field

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a Java class which contains a List field.

```
public class Machine{
    public int ID;

    public String Name;

    public String Status;

    public String Environment;

    public String Cluster;

    public List<String> SupportedLocales;
}
```

Below is an instance of the class in XML that I am trying to unmarshall.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Machine xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID>27</ID>
    <Name>QA14ADMINOPM201</Name>
    <Status>Decom</Status>
    <Environment>QA14</Environment>
    <Cluster>ADMINOPM</Cluster>
    <SupportedLocales>
        <SupportedLocale>NA</SupportedLocale>
        <SupportedLocale>Global</SupportedLocale>
    </SupportedLocales>
</Machine>
```

When I unmarshall the Xml though, the resulting object has an empty `SupportedLocales` list, with no elements. Any reason why this might be happening or suggested fixes? All other fields are being unmarshalled correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate your field with an [`XmlElementWrapper`](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) annotation:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "SupportedLocales")
@XmlElement(name = "SupportedLocale")
public List<String> SupportedLocales;
```

Also try to follow the convention of using variables that start with a lowercase (`supportedLocales` instead of `SupportedLocales`). This would need to map the XML element name for each field as follows:

```
@XmlElement(name="ID")
public int id;

@XmlElement(name="Name")
public String name;

@XmlElement(name="Status")
public String status;

@XmlElement(name="Environment")
public String environment;

@XmlElement(name="Cluster")
public String cluster;

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "SupportedLocales")
@XmlElement(name = "SupportedLocale")
public List<String> supportedLocales;
```

Comment: Yes, and the conventions ;-)

Comment: @manouti thanks! And I would use camel case but the classes I'm creating are based on C# classes and the field names need to match the C# names so that objects gotten from the API can be deserialized into Java classes. I don't know a way around it.

Comment: Yes you can specify the mapping for each field using annotations. Updated my answer.